# XML-RPC HTTP request with App Inventor?

Tags: php, xml, xmlhttprequest, app-inventor

I am trying to build out an app that will communicate with Tapatalks API, it uses XML-RPC HTTP requests, I can do post/get requests with the web component. I cannot find anything on modifying the web component/Blocks to create said XML-RPC encoding. Any resources? Tips of what to search, or insight would be appreciated.

This is the API php code I am trying to interact with https://github.com/tapatalk/tapatalk-phpbb3/blob/master/root/mobiquo/function/login.php

Here is my app blocks currently and I am getting a code 200

Here is my blocks editor : https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xqZp.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you tried looks very strange, but at least you tried something ;-) ... 
You somehow mixed a POST and GET request, there is no header defined and where is the xml format?

Probably it helps to read this first: [What is a XML-RPC Request](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/xml-rpc/xml_rpc_request.htm)
Then concerning **App Inventor** you can try to use the following blocks.
 
**EDIT:** update of the screenshot to make things clearer.

[image]

Comment: I must admit, you are amazing... and I thank you for spending your time with me. I am doing some research on XML-RPC requests and you have helped me greatly... Here is the setup I have.. I am not quite understanding how to make the method for getContentlength, I used a byte calculator to calculate the ammount of XML but user/pass are variables and that makes me draw a blank. Also my newfound understanding is that XMLRPC is going to reply a different location can you please advise. This is all to integrate with tapa talk API which is available with instructions: http://www.tapatalk.com/api.php

Comment: see the updated screenshot to avoid the custom procedure getContentLength. Btw: check your XML, this is no valid XML.