# Cannot find Web1.PostText (and others) in app inventor 2

Tags: android, app-inventor

I'd like to construct an app which lets you search for players in various online databases and which will display the content in webviewer.
While its easy with some services (since the target-url basically is `url/nickname`), with some services i need the app to enter the nickname in the search field and search for it.
As I was searching for answers I found the following topic
[XML-RPC HTTP request with App Inventor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744437/xml-rpc-http-request-with-app-inventor)

I'm not quite sure whether this is what I've been searching for, still I'd love to experiment with `Web1.PostText` and `Web1.RequestHeaders`, but I cannot find these blocks in `App Inventor 2`.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the [App Inventor documentation of the web component](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/components/connectivity.html#Web)

> **RequestHeaders**
>       The request headers, as a list of two-element sublists. The first element of each sublist represents the request header field name. The second element of each sublist represents the request header field values, either a single value or a list containing multiple values.
>
> **PostText(text text)**
>       Performs an HTTP POST request using the Url property and the specified text.
>       The characters of the text are encoded using UTF-8 encoding.
>       If the SaveResponse property is true, the response will be saved in a file and the GotFile event will be triggered. The responseFileName property can be used to specify the name of the file.
>       If the SaveResponse property is false, the GotText event will be triggered.

[image]