# Building a SOAP style post request XML for MIT App Inventor?

Tags: xml, soap, app-inventor

I am new to MIT App Inventor and able to work my way through the UI functions but not very sure about how to make a SOAP style post request from a web component.

I am able to do this with Python 2.7 and here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8

import requests

## Remeber: Way too many people accessing this server error may occur if any other instance is opened

request = u"""<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
        <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns="" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="http://localhost/HTSI_Pages/HTSI_DataService" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <writeString xmlns="http://localhost/HTSI_Pages/HTSI_DataService">
        <tagStr>MASTER.STATEMASTER</tagStr>
        <entryStr>ReadyAllManagers</entryStr>
        <typeStr>String</typeStr></writeString></SOAP-ENV:Body>
        </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>"""

encoded_request = request.encode('utf-8')

headers = {"Host": "10.216.224.30",
           "Content-Type": "text/xml; charset=UTF-8",
           "Content-Length": len(encoded_request)}

response = requests.post(url="http://10.216.224.30/HTSI_Pages/HTSI_DataService.asmx",
                         headers = headers,
                         data = encoded_request,
                         verify=False)

print unicode(response.text)
```

With a bit of googling i could find @[Taifun's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744437/xml-rpc-http-request-with-app-inventor) fantastic answer that shows if I have to make it work probably my best bet is to build the XML in the form of a list under web.request headers.

So, I'm  at this point not sure where and how i can encode the request in utf-8 format and set host/charset etc.(As I said, noob @ App Inventor)

PS: As it is an actual machine which responds to this request, I am restraining myself from trying out all possible combination of options to finally figure out the answer though thats what is my usual first peference.(The server inside the machine is in an embedded PLC, wasn't written by me, so i'm not sure how it will react to a different combinations.)

So,  any help to design this request in App Inventor will be greatly appreciated.

Update: I followed the steps and arrived at this block.
On click of the button I am now getting an error `Error 1103: unable to post or put text`. Followed by the uriencoded xml.

The screen is not big enough to see the complete error, but some googling suggests this might be due to firewall/network. What is your suggestion?

[image: Update:]

Update 2: So I set the screen scrollable, removed \n , Charset and semicolon, took the length of Uri encoded xml, and ran it against the `PostText` as well as `PostTextWithEncoding`.

None of them are raising the event `GotText`,  I suppose as the label text is not getting set but I'm getting the error in some kind of a popup message. Image attached.

[image: Update:2]

Comment: I have added an update to the original question with the relevant block @Taifun. Thank you for looking into this.

Comment: okay, working on these and will reply in a bit. Another thing... When building the XML, should i use \n to format it for newline or should i leave it the way it is after copy pasting from the text file i'm using as a repository. Note: In the text file I have the xml content in a usual new line formatted way.

Comment: Tried the steps, and updated the issue, it's still not there yet, btw, I can't thank you enough for sticking out with me on this @Taifan.

Comment: Okey, i'm out of the office so will try it out within 12 hrs and get back on this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129067/discussion-between-s4nd33p-and-taifun).

Comment: please provide an update of your blocks and the result, see also my answer with the summary of all the tips up to now... Sorry, I'm not available for a chat...

Comment: Hi Taifun, starting where I left off, I added the Screen.ErrorOccurred event to a label and was able to finally see the complete error message. Though not much help it was, I also came out of my office network and tried to use the app to call the post method and received the same error. Which then led me to think if it's not the syntax, but in my office desktops and mobiles are connected to 2 different network and perhaps due to this the request is not reaching the server.

Comment: So I have shoot up a mail to have word with the server management folks and waiting for them to be back after thanksgiving, but as soon as i find a solution for this I will come back here and update the issue. I thought after so much help I owe you this much to inform you on what was the progress.

Answer (score 1):

Some tips

- You might want to look at another example, [how to set the request headers](https://puravidaapps.com/dropbox.php) and in your case use the `PostText` method to post your request. To encode the request, use the UriEncode method.
- don't use `\n`
- To get the complete error message, set the screen to scrollable=true and display the result in a label. Make sure to set `Web.SaveResponse` to false and use the `Web.GotText` event to receive the result. You can try `text/xml` as Content-Type (remove the semicolon and the charset part). Is the string `StrXml` as expected? Use *Do it* to find it out, see also Tip 4 here [Top 5 Tips: How to learn App Inventor](https://puravidaapps.com/learn.php)
- The error currently is displayed from the `Screen.ErrorOccurred` event, you also can add a label there to display the error on the screen. To use the `PostTextWithEncoding` method is a good idea. Remove the `UriEncode` blocks, probably that's the issue. Also you could remove all these unnecessary spaces in the XML string...